# Where is “WD SmartWare” stored on the drive?

Tags: external-hard-drive

My Western Digital external harddrive came with a (so-far useless) extra chunk of information (named *WD Smartware*) that mounts itself every time I plug in the external harddrive.

I assumed it was stored as a second partition on the drive, however, upon opening GParted, the only partition that shows up is the main 340 GBs for the drive itself. Where is this extra 400 MB of data being stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's implemented as a virtual CD, created by the drive's firmware. It cannot be removed. However, you can tell the drive not to present it if that's what you'd prefer -- see [How to Disable the WD VCD](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fj5P7ZBlV4M&feature=related).